# Material Design - floating action button hiding in listview scroll (like in google+)

Tags: android, listview, scroll, material-design, floating-action-button

Hello how do I hide a floating action button when scrolling down like in the Google+ app?

I have seen various ways of detecting scrolling in a listview, but what I've seen so far is only detecting the rendering of child cells as they move on/off screen. This isn't what Google+  is doing at all and this won't work for me because I have a large header cell and it is painfully obvious that the floating action button does not disappear fast enough.

Any insight appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this project has couple of example of hiding and showing fab button, actionbar and tabs.

https://github.com/lawloretienne/QuickReturn

Comment: Can you explain *how* the project you linked achieves this? As is, this is a poor answer because it is only a link

Answer (score 10):

Google plus doesn't use `ListView`, it uses the new `RecyclerView` the new `RecyclerView` have an `OnScrollListener` that receives pixels scrolled. They then use standard View animations and transformations to move the thing out of view. With `View.setTranslationY(val)`; and `View.animate().setTranslationYBy(val);`

Comment: oh cool, that is in the v7 compatibility pack, if it takes an adapter then I might use that instead

Comment: yes, it does use an adapter. There're a few small differences from ListView, but there's a lot of tutorials around and it's easy to get port it over.

Comment: Does `RecyclerView` have the functionality as `ListView`? I mean does it handle the list like `ListView` does? I'm new to this materialized android environtment.

Comment: @SyarifIbnuMiftahudinAl-Dami RecyclerView is a better ListView. There are differences on how to implement, but it is much much better. It has nothing to do with material design. The design depends on what you put in your adapter